# Return situation-dependent messages (exceptions)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, unique, plpgsql

I've got stored procedures in my PostgreSQL environment. One of these procedures stores user defined data.

In plpgsql-language, I would like to realize the following processing:

Because there are unique constraints in the destination-table, I first check, if the affected attributes are already in this table. If so, I want the stored procedure to return these affected attributes, so the user knows: "Uh, some of my data already exists, let's try something different!"

**For example** a part of the affected table:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
  Name varchar UNIQUE
  ...
)
```

Now I want to add a new row to `XYZ`. If the function notices that the name already exists it should return a message with the offending `name`. There can be **multiple** duplicates and the function should return all of them. How can this be implemented?

I first thought to check every attribute individually, but that's very slow:

```sql
-- Check, if abbreviation or name already exist.
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    "sample-scheme"."sample-table" AS tableName
  WHERE
    tableName.abbreviation = argAbbreviation
  OR
    tableName.name = argName
)
INTO
  varEntryExists;

-- If abbreviation or name exists, return error message.
IF varEntryExists THEN
  RETURN "Already exists.";
END IF;
```

This sample also doesn't return the offending attribute.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this simple query:

```
SELECT name
FROM   XYZ
JOIN   unnest ('{name1, name2, name3}'::varchar[]) AS n(name) USING (name);
```

Or use the ["is contained by" operator `<@`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) (faster for small arrays):

```
SELECT name
FROM   XYZ
WHERE  name <@ '{name1, name2, name3}'::varchar[]
```

Wrapped into a function, to return multiple finds, you can either return an array or `RETURNS SETOF ...` or `RETURNS TABLE(...)` to return a set. Demonstrating a plpgsql function (could also just be SQL), with a convenient `VARIADIC` parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_name_dupes(VARIADIC _names varchar[])
  RETURNS SETOF varchar AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT name
   FROM   XYZ x
   WHERE  name <@ $1;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_name_dupes('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
```

Returns all names that already exist in table `XYZ`. More details for `VARIADIC`:

- [How to do WHERE x IN (val1, val2,…) in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61520/how-to-do-where-x-in-val1-val2-in-plpgsql/61552#61552)